# getSourceClassName method in java logRecord gives null value

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to include the Class name and method name in log file. Am using the following code.

```
public String format(LogRecord record)
{
    StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
            .
            .
            if( record.getSourceClassName() != null )
    {
        buff.append( "Source class: " );
        buff.append( record.getSourceClassName() + " Method : " + record.getSourceMethodName() + '\n' );
    }
    else if( record.getSourceClassName() == null )
    {
        buff.append( "class name null" );//<-- always getting null
    }
}
```

But i'm getting only null value for class name. I'm using log4j and using my own formatter class. I'm new to java logging kindly anyone suggest me.

Comment: Are you using Java Util Logging o log4j?

Comment: i'm using java.util.Logging only!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a custom layout extending the class [`org.apache.log4j.Layout`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Layout.html), e.g.:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Layout;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

public class MyLayout extends Layout {
    public void activateOptions() {
        // None action
    }

    public String format(LoggingEvent event) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(event.getLevel());
        sb.append(" (");
        sb.append(event.getLoggerName());
        sb.append(":");
        sb.append(event.getLocationInformation().getLineNumber());
        sb.append(") - ");
        sb.append(event.getMessage());
        sb.append(LINE_SEP);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public boolean ignoresThrowable() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

For get the name of the class, you need to declare one static field and passing the class reference object in your *client* class:

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class);
```

See more in *Appenders and Layouts* from [*Short introduction to log4j*](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).

Comment: Layout class helps ! Do I need to pass Source class name from client class or else can I use `record.getSourceClassName()` method in that formatter class?

Answer (score -1):

You can use **`record.getClass().getName();`** and show the name class.

Comment: `record.getClass().getName()` gives 'java.util.logging` but what i need is to get the Source class from where the log message is generated.

Comment: try record.getSourceMethodName()